# ignored tags get concatenated when adding without reloading

Tags: bug, status-declined, ignored-tags

Whenever I specify mulitple ignored tags, without reloading the get concatenated to one tag.

I write sinatra. I click add.
I write rails. I click add.
I reload the page and get sinatrarails.

This does not happen when I reload beetween adding tags.

I am using konqueror 4.3.1

Comment: cannot reproduce on firefox 3.5.5...

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly a konqueror issue; it's not one of our primary supported browsers.